# Nightwatch.js test in multi browser environment is looping the test

Tags: node.js, selenium, nightwatch.js

Hi I have the following simple nightwatch demo script which is looping when ran with **multiple browser** environment, but which **works fine if I run the test with single browser**.

**Following arguments loops the test:**

```
        var argv = {
            test: 'nightwatchgoogletest.js',
            config: 'nightwatch.json',
            reporter: 'junit',
            env : 'default,chrome'
        };
```

**Following works fine:**

```
        var argv = {
            test: 'nightwatchgoogletest.js',
            config: 'nightwatch.json',
            reporter: 'junit',
            env : 'chrome' (or default or any single browser)
        };
```

Following is my code, please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

**nightwatchgoogletest.js** :

```js
module.exports = {
  
  'Demo test Google' : function (client) {
    client
      .url('http://google.no')
      .pause(1000);

    // expect element  to be present in 1000ms
    client.expect.element('body').to.be.present.before(1000);

    // expect element <#lst-ib> to have css property 'display'
    client.expect.element('#lst-ib').to.have.css('display');

    // expect element  to have attribute 'class' which contains text 'vasq'
    client.expect.element('body').to.have.attribute('class').which.contains('vasq');

    // expect element <#lst-ib> to be an input tag
    client.expect.element('#lst-ib').to.be.an('input');

    // expect element <#lst-ib> to be visible
    client.expect.element('#lst-ib').to.be.visible;

    client.end();
  }
};
```

And have written the following **node** script to call above test:

```js
var Nightwatch = require('nightwatch');

function proceess_test() {
    try {
        var argv = {
            test: 'nightwatchgoogletest.js',
            config: 'nightwatch.json',
            reporter: 'junit',
            env : 'default,chrome'
        };

        console.log("\n>> Initiating Tests for ...",process.env.__NIGHTWATCH_ENV_KEY);
        var settings = {};
        var done = function() {console.log("done")};
        Nightwatch.runner(argv, done, settings);
        done();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Exception: ' + error.message);
    }
}

proceess_test();
```

With the following nightwatch configuration:
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=7e8e1616d595417ceeafaccc6358b33d

But when I run the test, it going in an **infinite testing loop** as follows:

[image: nightwatch looping the test]
[image: nightwatch looping the test]

Comment: I would send an issue to the github page if I were you.

Comment: Oh yeah I have created there now https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/674